# How do you delete/move a row based on the value of a cell changing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a "Task" tab that has a priority and status for each task. I want to delete the task from "Tasks" and add a row to "Completed Tasks" when the status of that task changes to completed. I've been playing around with Macro and the on edit feature. But it's a little complicated for me because both my tables of data are on different rows and columns. So it's not lining up very well. I'll post my spreadsheet to help give you guys a better idea of what I'm talking about.

Google Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rnICvztZiKXXeXX6ZZhmeJ99BS0yS_K4HAEAuLHEbyA/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried using Macro and using a for loop of sorts. But it's just a big mess now

Comment: can you please provide the code you've tried and results? Also I think you should look into how to implement triggers:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

that may assist you as you can have your script/function perform action(s) if certain criteria happens

Comment: Hi and welcome. Thanks for attaching a spreadsheets. I appreciate that your "tables of data are on different rows and columns" but would you please show this in your question. Your question should stand on its own - please do NOT expect that volunteers must open and review your spreadsheet in order to understand your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. Just a few things to note:

- You are correct that you need to use onEdit, but it needs to be an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). You can install the trigger manually - just follow the instructions.
- You need to make use of [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). This gives you access to the name of the edited sheet, the edited value, and the edited row.

---

```
function clearRow(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // define the edit Sheet Name for use in the IF
  var editSheetName = "Tasks"
  var editSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tasks"); 

  // get the eddited value for use in the IF
  var eVal = e.value

  // test for the "Tasks" sheet and for the tick mark
  if(ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() === editSheetName && eVal === '✅'){

    // define the target sheet
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Tasks")
    // get the editted row
    var eRowStart = e.range.rowStart
    // get the last row in the target sheet
    var targetLR = targetSheet.getLastRow()
    // define the range in the edit sheet and 'Get' the values
    var editValues = editSheet.getRange(eRowStart,1,1,5).getValues()
    // define the range in the target sheet and 'set the Values
    targetSheet.getRange(targetLR,1,1,5).setValues(editValues)
    // delete the edited row in the edit sheet
    editSheet.deleteRow(eRowStart)
  }    
  else{
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: no match")
  }
}
```

---